# Add CSS styles with PrototypeJS

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a `div` that I want to add a new style to using PrototypeJS. But the following script does not work. What is wrong with it?

```
<div class='exercise-main'>
</div>

$$('.exercise-main').setStyle({
    backgroundColor: '#900',
    fontSize: '12px'
});
```

Comment: If my answer helped out out, I'd appreciate it if you accepted my answer. Thanks! ( ^ _ ^ )

Answer (score 4):

The `$$` function returns an **array** of all matching elements (if any). `setStyle` is an **element** method, not an array method.

There are a few options here.

If you're only ever expecting a single element to be matched, this will work.

```
$$('.exercise-main')[0].setStyle({color:'red'});
```

If you want to set the style on every matched element, either of these will work. They're essentially the same.

```
$$('.exercise-main').each(function(element) {
    element.setStyle({color: 'red'});
});
```

or

```
$$('.exercise-main').invoke('setStyle', {color:'red'});
```

Of course, if your element has an id, you can use the `$` function to find just that element. This differs from `$$` in that you don't pass it a selector string, but just the string of the id (ie no '#'). Also, this returns just the element or null - not an array - so you can use element methods straight from the returned value, similar to what you were initially attempting.

```
$('myElementId').setStyle({color:'red'});
```